# Recommendations for a CLI-based image uploader to flickr for Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, upload, flickr

I'm looking for a decent CLI-based utility to upload images to flickr. Does anyone know of such a tool or script ?
I'm using openSUSE 11.2, to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be a built-in command line function to do this, but Lifehacker has a good article about a Flickr-upload Python script here:

http://lifehacker.com/262311/automatically-upload-a-folders-photos-to-flickr

Comment: Looks interesting - seems this is just what I require. Will check and update. Thanks!